# Integrate a Newsletter Sign-Up Form in mkdocs

Tags: email, newsletter, mkdocs

I know mkdocs is meant to be a static site without third-party integrations/forms.

I need to add a newsletter sign-up form to an mkdocs-generated page.

How can I do this? There seems to be 0% information about this online.

Answer (score 1):

MkDocs uses Markdown and Markdown can accept raw HTML and pass it through unaltered. Therefore, include an HTML form in one of your Markdown pages. Perhaps something like this:

```
Some Markdown text.

<form action="http://someothersite.com/" method="post">
    <P>
    <label for="name">Name: </label> <input type="text" id="name"><br>
    <label for="email">Email: </label> <input type="text" id="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </P>
</form>

More Markdown text.
```

Of course, as MkDocs is a static site, it will not be able to process the submission of the form. Therefore, the form will need to be submitted to some other service and/or script separate from MkDocs. For information on how to submit your form to a separate service, see the answers to [Cross Domain Form POSTing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11423682/edit).